# Meaning of “squire”

Tags: meaning, sentence

“It had been a long day covering Mr. Trump as he **squired** Prime Minister Shinzo Abe of Japan.”

Retrieved from

https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/28/us/politics/trump-white-house-first-100-days-new-york-times-reporters.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=b-lede-package-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=0

I look up the word “squire” and find a lot of definitions which I think they are irrelevant.

(1)Merriam Webster：to attend as a squire
(2)Oxford Living dictionaries：(of a man) accompany or escort (a woman)
(3)Dictionary.com：to escort (a woman), as to a dance or social gathering.

Are there above-mentioned definitions which are relevant?
If not, what is the correct definition?

Comment: The above definitions are correct and applicable.

Comment: @HotLicks Quite so! However, it would have been more appropriate and dipplomatic if it had been applied to the PM's wife, rather than the PM. It's use, certainly in the UK, has a man-on-woman connotation with just a faint hint of a coupling in the offing.

Comment: @PeterPoint - Appropriate and diplomatic?  Do keep in mind that we're talking about Mr Trump.  (And, in the US, "squire" is much less gender-specific than it likely is in the UK.)

Comment: @HotLicks Your reminder about President Trump is timely and so I suppose my choice of words is someting of a blundering misnomer on my part. I wasn't aware of any gender-specific issue in squiring my "date" when I lived and worked in New Your's Upper East Side. Strangely enough, my "dates" were always of the type that we stage-door Johnnies liked to squire in these sort of things.

Comment: I think it may have been purposely used to insert the image of *apprentice* into the sketch. This works at a couple levels here. The obvious one, and the fact that Abe is part of a political dynasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "squired" is being used as a *verb* in a colorful, playful way.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squire):

> to attend as a squire :  escort
>
> Examples of squire in a sentence: *her father squired her to the dance to make sure she got there all right*

So in this case it means that he escorted the Prime Minister around.  Since the article says that this took place at Mar-a-Lago, Trump's immense resort, it's a colorful way of saying that Trump showed Abe around, and probably tried to impress him in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an ornamental or literary use of the word **squire**.

> From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/squired)
>
> **Squire** verb (used with object), squired, squiring.
>
> *to attend as, or in the manner of, a squire.*
>
> **Squire** (Noun)
>
> 1.(in England) a country gentleman, especially the chief landed proprietor in a district.
>
> 2.(in the Middle Ages) a young man of noble birth who as an aspirant to knighthood served a knight.